# Conceptual Change thinking needed

Tags: field-theory

Using Conceptual Change Research To Reason About Curriculum

By Glenn D. Berkheimer, Charles W. Anderson, and Steven T. Spees

Introduction

The kinetic molecular theory is fundamental to the understanding of most of modern science. Feynman recognized this when he said:

If, in some cataclysm, all scientific knowledge were to be destroyed, and only one sentence passed on to the next generations of creatures, what statement would contain the most information in the fewest words? I believe it is the atomic hypothesis (or the atomic fact, or whatever you wish to call it) that all things are made of atoms—little particles that move around in perpetual motion, attracting each other when they are a little distance apart, but repelling upon being squeezed into one another. In that one sentence, you will see, there is an enormous amount of information about the world, if just a little imagination and thinking are applied. (Feynman, Leighton, & Sands, 1963)
The kinetic molecular theory is of fundamental importance in science due to its usefulness in explaining phenomena and changes in substances. For example, in biology it is used to explain basic processes such as diffusion, osmosis, photosynthesis and respiration. In earth science we use it to explain thermal expansion of solids, liquids, and gases, changes in density, and convection currents. In chemistry and physics we use the kinetic molecular theory to explain the nature of matter, changes of state of matter, pressure, the gas laws, and essential interactions among molecules that give rise to chemical reactions. It is, therefore, essential that students understand the kinetic molecular theory in sufficient depth so they can use it to understand and explain key processes and concepts in science.

Demonstration
1  https://vid.me/aFbm

2  https://vid.me/XLq5

Comment: The second video seems very clearly to be air pressure. The speed of sound is "instant" at these distances. It's harder to tell with the enclosed glass, but I'd bet it's not hard to find a way of enclosing the flame and/or putting it on a solid foundation that prevents the flame from moving. Your answer will be found in what's different between the two scenarios. You could try using materials of different types to test the electromagnetic theories, or putting the candle in a chamber suspended in a vacuum chamber to test pressure waves. Etc. But I intuitively doubt the answer is that complex.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here (which is a necessity when posting on a *question* and answer site such as this).

Comment: the only knowledge to transmit is *"survive and open your mind"*. Unless the next generations survive in extremal conditions, they would be able to find again all what we call and classify in the maths and the physics, maybe with less lacks than us.

Comment: @igael- Only if they lacked power,greed and control. What a lovely generation they would be.

Answer (score 1):

While you quickly move your hands you produce all kind of mechanical waves and also air currents that reach the candle and this is the reason the flame moves.

For example in [one of you videos](https://vid.me/aFbm), showing a candle inside a glass box, the box stays on a few books that are on a table. When you move your hands you transmit vibrations to the floor (because your entire body shakes) and from the floor the vibration propagate to the table and further to the box and candle.

Your phenomenon has a simple mechanical explanation.

There have been made similar experiments, like [Demonstration of sympathetic vibration using the optical (flame) microphone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-4Qw9-Lnr8), where the flame reacts to the music.

Comment: Its enclosed in glass and the flame moves in synchronicity with my hands at the exact same moment.The second video with the 3 in book in front was to show this force is not affected by matter. Please analyse the video in slow or fast motion before debunking it with wind, Im not trying to insult the communities knowlege.

Comment: @Mr.Who: Energizer's explanation is as good as anyone's, in the absence of a proper description of your set up and not just two measly videos that shows very little of what is going on. You seem oblivious to the fact that *extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence*. In that sense you *are* insulting this community's knowledge, although possibly inadvertently.

Comment: filming with a camera causes the flame to look more of a glob of glare. with the naked eye I can get the same result moving with the slightest movement.So I have to get the most movement to be noticed through the camera because of the globe of glare shown through the camera.Its really hard to film and show my interaction and the flame at the right angle to see movement to the viewer.

Comment: I asked the community because they should know 20 more suggestions then the simplest explanation to give.Please don't reply with wind, rather just vote down.

Comment: @Mr.Who: You keep bringing up 'wind', which is kind of funny as air currents are by far the most likely explanation. Whether or not an explanation is 'simple' or not has no bearing on its validity but do look up *Occam's Razor*. As a flame is no more that a hot, reacting gas, invoking air currents as the cause of motion is by far the most likely explanation.